# ¿Cómo transformar las líneas de un marco de datos en una lista de diccionario excepto para un ámbito exterior?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, diccionarios

Para probar [mi primer paquete](https://test.pypi.org/project/multilabelclassificationtree/), me gustaría transformar un marco de datos que he convertido en un diccionario:

```
data = [{'Age': 20, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 600, "party": 'PartyB'},
        {'Age': 30, 'Quartier': 'B', 'Income': 675, "party": "PartyA"},
        {'Age': 40, 'Quartier': 'C', 'Income': 3000, "party":'ABS'},
        {'Age': 50, 'Quartier': 'D', 'Income': 4000, "party": 'ABS'}]
```

A los siguientes

```
data = [({'Age': 20, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 600}, 'PartyB'),
        ({'Age': 30, 'Quartier': 'B', 'Income': 675}, "PartyA"),
        ({'Age': 40, 'Quartier': 'C', 'Income': 3000}, 'ABS'),
        ({'Age': 50, 'Quartier': 'D', 'Income': 4000}, 'ABS')]
```

Además, si tiene algún comentario sobre cómo mejorarlo, no lo dude.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte de `dict.pop` para extraer el valor y eliminar la clave:

```
data = [{'Age': 20, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 600, "party": 'PartyB'},
        {'Age': 30, 'Quartier': 'B', 'Income': 675, "party": "PartyA"},
        {'Age': 40, 'Quartier': 'C', 'Income': 3000, "party":'ABS'},
        {'Age': 50, 'Quartier': 'D', 'Income': 4000, "party": 'ABS'}]

data = [(diccionario, diccionario.pop("party")) for diccionario in data]
```

> ```
> >>> data
> [({'Age': 20, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 600}, 'PartyB'),
>  ({'Age': 30, 'Quartier': 'B', 'Income': 675}, 'PartyA'),
>  ({'Age': 40, 'Quartier': 'C', 'Income': 3000}, 'ABS'),
>  ({'Age': 50, 'Quartier': 'D', 'Income': 4000}, 'ABS')]
> ```

Si tu diccionario es el resultado de `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict(orient="records")` puedes hacer un filtro antes de llamar al método, descartando la columna y agregarla de forma externa a `to_dict`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
       [{'Age': 20, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 600, "party": 'PartyB'},
        {'Age': 30, 'Quartier': 'B', 'Income': 675, "party": "PartyA"},
        {'Age': 40, 'Quartier': 'C', 'Income': 3000, "party":'ABS'},
        {'Age': 50, 'Quartier': 'D', 'Income': 4000, "party": 'ABS'}]
        )
```

> ```
> >>> df
>   Age Quartier    Income  party
> 0 20         A    600     PartyB
> 1 30         B    675     PartyA
> 2 40         C    3000    ABS
> 3 50         D    4000    ABS
> ```

```
data = [(diccionario, party) for diccionario, party in zip(
    df.loc[:, df.columns != 'party'].to_dict(orient="records"), df["party"]
    )]
```

> ```
> >>> data
> [({'Age': 20, 'Quartier': 'A', 'Income': 600}, 'PartyB'),
>  ({'Age': 30, 'Quartier': 'B', 'Income': 675}, 'PartyA'),
>  ({'Age': 40, 'Quartier': 'C', 'Income': 3000}, 'ABS'),
>  ({'Age': 50, 'Quartier': 'D', 'Income': 4000}, 'ABS')]
> ```